# Alexa Skill - How to make a voice pin authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to Alexa skill development. I'm trying to create a voice pin authentication.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

*User: "Turn ON the light"*

*Alexa: "What is your security pin?"*

*User: "6456" (Wrong pin)*

*Alexa: "Authentication failed! Please try again."*

*User: "1234" (Correct pin)*

*Alexa: "Turning ON the light!"*

If the user tells the correct pin the first time there is no issue, but if the user tells a wrong pin the first time Alexa just says the reprompt message and doesn't take the new pin value, how will I get the new pin value and check that pin once again in the same intent handler?

This is my code:

```
const RemoteControlIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
        && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'RemoteControlIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    var speakOutput = '';
    var userPin = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.securityPin.value;
    
    if (userPin !== userSecurityPin) {
        speakOutput = 'Authentication Failed! Please retry!';
        
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
            
    } else {
        speakOutput = 'Turning ON the light!';
        
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other intent containing FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER only?

Comment: What error are you getting when you state the second PIN?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `RemoteControlIntent` is not mapped with pin utterance. so, when you tries with actual pin second time alexa does not know with which intent it should be mapped.

You need a way to again execute `RemoteControlIntent` with the actual pin.

It would require your intent schema to properly solve the problem, but here is a solution that will work

```
const RemoteControlIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
      return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
      && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'RemoteControlIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
     var speakOutput = '';
     var userPin =handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.securityPin.value;
     const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
     if (userPin !== userSecurityPin) {
       speakOutput = 'Authentication Failed! Please retry!';
       return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        .addElicitSlotDirective('securityPin') // this line will ask for the pin again against the same intent
        .getResponse();        
     } else {
       speakOutput = 'Turning ON the light!';
       return handlerInput.responseBuilder
             .speak(speakOutput)
             .reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the 
              user to respond')
             .withShouldEndSession(true)
             .getResponse();
    }
  }
};
```

Remeber to **enable auto delegation** for `RemoteControlIntent` and use **What is your security pin?** in the `securityPin` prompt.